# Separating convex sets in a tvs $X$.

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

I got doubt with the proof of this theorem.

> Let $X$ be a tvs, $A,B \subset X$ with $A$ an open convex set and $B$ convex such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Then there exists $f \in X^*$ (where $X^*$ is the topological dual of $X$) that satisfies
>   $$
> f(a)< \inf_{b \in B} f(b)
> $$

***proof:***

We already know that, given a tvs $X$, a convex set $A\subset X$ with $A$ open, and a point $x_0$ such that $ x_0 \not \in A$, then there exists $f \in X^*$ with
$$
f(a)<f(x_0) \quad \forall a \in A
$$
With this, in order to prove the above theorem, we can take $C\dot{=} A-B$, which is convex and open, and separate $C$ from $0$, i.e., exists $f \in X^*$ such that
$$
f(a-b)< f(0)=0 \quad \forall a,b \in A,B
$$
and, since $A$ is open we conclude that the last inequality implies 
$$
f(a)<\inf_{b \in B} f(b)
$$
**My doubt is**: Can we, with the same hypothesis (i.e. $A$ open and convex, $B$ just convex and disjoint from $A$) of the above theorem, change the roles of $A$ and $B$ in order to obtain:
$$
f(b)< \inf_{a \in A} f(a) \quad \forall b \in B
$$
Any hint would be welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the case of $B$ containing a single point $b$. Located conveniently, you _must_ have $f(b) \geqslant \inf\limits_{a\in A} f(a)$ for every $f\in X^\ast$.

Comment: If we assume that $A,B$ are convex, this is similar to the first geometric form of Hahn-Banach theorem Which implies the existence of a hyperplane separating $A,B$.

Comment: @DanielFischer With "located conveniently" you mean, for instance, take $b \in \bar{A}$ (assuming $\bar{A} \setminus{A} \neq \emptyset$).

Comment: Right. And the boundary of a nonempty convex open set that isn't the entire space is always nonempty. (I forgot to mention the restriction $A\neq\varnothing$.)

Comment: @Hamid Sorry, I meant that theorem. I edited the post

Comment: @Juan Pablo You are welcome.